# Counting events in data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I would like to count occurrences within the data frame with 100 rows for 100 users and  5 columns for the userID, all conducted events and the thress events separately.
For each user I would like to count in column 3 to 5 the events separately which are listed in column 2 together in "" and separated by a comma (for example (c("stroke", "mouseclick1","mouseclick2")).

My code looks like this:

```
frame <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = length(my.data))) 

x <-c("user","eventsall","mouseclick1","mouseclick2","stroke")

colnames(frame) <- x
frame$user <- c(1:length(my.data))
frame$eventsall <- as.character(frame$workflow)
frame$mouseclick1 <- ?????
frame$mouseclick2 <- ?????
frame$stroke <- ?????
```

How can I define the three variables (above) so that I am able to **count the frequency of each event for each user** within the frame?

The first loop is correct but the second is wrong which I could repeat for 
mouseclick2 and stroke. Is the function **str_count** correct?

```
for (i in frame$user) {
  if (is.na(my.data[[i]][["scenario1"]]) == TRUE) {
    frame$eventsall[i] <- NA
  }
  else {
    frame$eventsall[i] <- list(my.data[[i]][["scenario1"]][["events.all"]])
  }
}

for (i in frame$user) {
  if (is.na(my.data[[i]][["scenario1"]][["events.all"]]) == TRUE) {
    frame$mouseclick1[i] <- NA
  }
  else {
    frame$mouseclick1[i,3] <- str_count(my.data[[i]][["scenario1"]][["events.all", pattern="mouseclick1"]])
  }
}
View(frame)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide a some data, that we can use to devise the answer with. See [the reproducible example guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can split the comma delimited string using `strsplit` and then loop through each row of the data.

```
# Sample data since none was provided
frame <- data.frame(user=c(1:5),
                    eventsall=c('1,2,3',
                                '3,4,6',
                                '5,3,2',
                                '7,4,5',
                                '6,6,5'))

frame$eventsall <- as.character(frame$eventsall)

events.split <- strsplit(frame$eventsall,',')

for(i in 1:nrow(frame)){
  frame$mouseclick1[i] <- events.split[[i]][1]
  frame$mouseclick2[i] <- events.split[[i]][2]
  frame$stroke[i] <- events.split[[i]][3]
}
```